# Disable button taps for duration of time iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsuserdefaults, reporting

**Concept:** When `userA` reports `userB` I need to disable the report button for duration of time so that `userA` can't repeatedly report same user.

**Solution:** Store data in NSUserDefaults where the `key` would be a `String` like `report_userBId` and `value` would be a timestamp 24 hours out from current date (of type `Double`). This way, each time `userA` attempts to report another user, I check `NSUserDefaults` to see if `userA` already reported `userB`. If so, I check if current time is greater than the stored timestamp, and if so, remove data from `NSUserDefaults` and allow user to send report.

I have not actually implemented this solution yet, and would like to know if this is the type of problem where NSUserDefaults is the best solution, or should I use something like Core Data?

Comment: i think it depends.  If you're already using Core Data to store other data, then you might as well store a few more timestamps.  If not, then it's a bit of overkill for such a small requirement - and NSUserDefaults might be better

Comment: @Russell I see... This project uses Core Data extensively. Would you create an entity named `Report` that contains timestamp and id of reportedUser, and add a `reports` attribute (of type  to `NSSet`) to `User` Entity?

Comment: @Russel, you should write a detailed answer so he will accept it... I don't know much about CoreData.. Too complicated for me =]

Comment: Anon - yes - I would go for something like that - with the same check & remove you discussed for the defaults option.  I'm away from my Mac for a while, so I can't give you an example - but if you're already using Core Data I think you know what to do :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely agree with @Russel.

Using CoreData for this task is like kill a mosquito with a rocket!

If you've already implemented and used it, you may add support, otherwise, just use NSDefaults...